# Meta: Burninate [merge-request]

Tags: discussion, burnination-request

The tag [merge-request](/questions/tagged/merge-request) on Meta has 7 question, of which have many different interpretations of the tag. All these questions if they really need the tag can create a more specific one.

Stats:

- 0 followers
- 7 questions
- No tag wiki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have removed the tag from the 7 questions that had it, so it will be deleted automatically by the system.

No need to do anything else.